# unable to show image from external hd php

Tags: php, arrays, image, file-get-contents, hard-drive

I'm new with programming and learning now php. I have installed xamp and have write a little bit code. I have some images on my external hd and I want to show some pictures.
The problem is I can get a list of path of my images with this code:

```
   echo "<html><body>";
   $outerDir = "x:\map\maps\more\\";
   $total = count (array_diff (scandir ($outerDir), Array (".", "..")));
   $dirs = array_diff( scandir( $outerDir ), Array( ".", ".." ) ); 
   foreach ($dirs as $d) {
       if (!is_dir($outerDir . $d)) {
           echo $d . "<br>";
       }
   }
```

but if I want to show it as an image, i can't show the image. I tried this in the foreach:

```
if (!is_dir($outerDir . $d)) {
    $file = $outerhDir . $d;
    echo 'img src="' . $outerDir . $d . '> <br>';
    echo "<img src='" . $outerDir . '\\' . $d . "'alt='" . $d . "'> <br>";
}
```

But none of them work. I also tried the header and file_get_content like this:

```
if (!is_dir($outerDir . $d)) {
    $file = $outerDir . $d;
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Length:' . filesize($file));
    $image = file_get_contents('$file');
    echo $image . "<br>";
}
```

Even a simple html code wont work! Like this:

```
echo '<img src="x:\map\maps\more\needwonder.jpg"> <br>';
```

BUTTTT!! When I store one of the image in the same folder as my php file it will work! Like this:

```
echo '<img src="needwonder.jpg"> <br>';
```

But I dont want to put all my files in the same folder as the php file, because of security, technicaly, comfortable reasons AND I want to learn programming not to avoid issues or problems with my code.

So I hope I defined my problem good and hope that one of you guys and/or girls know the solution to help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image files aren't in a folder that's set up to be accessible by the web server, you can't display them on a web page. Simple as that. Put them in a web directory to use them.

It is possible to write a PHP script that proxies image files (kind of like what you're trying with `file_get_contents()`), but doing that requires a separate PHP file for the images, and it's best avoided unless absolutely necessary, as it can easily introduce security vulnerabilities, and performs poorly. If you do want to do that, though:

- Link to the PHP script in place of an image, and pass it an identifier for the image as a parameter (e.g, `<img src="img.php?image=blah">`).
- In that script, use that identifier to send the appropriate Content-Type, then use `readfile()` to output the image. (It's equivalent to `echo file_get_contents(...)`, but more concise and performs better in some situations.)
- **MAKE ABSOLUTELY SURE** that the parameter to that script cannot be manipulated to load a file that you didn't intend to make available. This includes trickery like `?image=../../wrong/file`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so is it better to use another language instead of php? If yes, wich one is better? Java, C#, C++? When I master the basics of PHP, I also want t learn other languages

Comment: This isn't a language-specific issue. Switching to another language will not solve it.